cpanel configure Apache for laravel-reverb
i can't configure Apache in cpanel for laravel reverb in production service
i found nothing to try
all blogs, articles and GitHub issues are about nginx and nothing about Apache or cpanel i did not find a clear tutorial to follow

after i finally i manage to configure apache2
i got this error
[ERROR] Laravel\Reverb\Protocols\Pusher\Http\Controllers\PusherController::__invoke(): Argument #2 ($connection) must
be of type Laravel\Reverb\Servers\Reverb\Connection, Laravel\Reverb\Servers\Reverb\Http\Connection given,
called in /home/user/public_html/chat.usernet/vendor/laravel/reverb/src/Servers/Reverb/Http/Router.php on
line 69
and don't know why

the same problem here
